# Sitecore controller rendering causing StackOverflowException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I am trying to do a simple controller rendering with Sitecore 8 and for some reason it's producing a `StackOverflowException` on the line within the main layout markup that contains the reference to the placeholder it is to be rendered in. This seems to crash the worker process, but you can see the stack overflow on debugging the process:

[image: w3p crash]
[image: StackOverflow]

Here is my very basic controller:

[image: Controller/View]

And here is my controller rendering definition:

[image]

Reproduction notes:

1. This is occurring in a vanilla Sitecore 8 installation (rev. 150427 -installed via SIM).
2. The MVC project is also vanilla -created with empty ASP.NET project, then NuGetting in MVC 5.1.
3. Web.config & Global added to project from the Sitecore site root in `wwwroot`.

FYI - everything is absolutely fine doing a view rendering - it's just controller renderings that seem to be causing a problem

Comment: I didn't get this solution for a while, when searched for **unhandled microsoft .net framework exception w3wp sitecore stackoverflow**, finally this question was a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was actually pretty simple in the end.

Returning a `ViewResult` when the view is intended as a partial view (which all Sitecore renderings will be) then you must set the layout property in the markup to null:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Otherwise MVC will try to wrap the layout file around it, which of course contains your Sitecore placeholder, which causes an infinite loop and crashes the worker process with a `StackOverflowException`.

So in the context of Sitecore, either return a PartialViewResult or return a ViewResult with the layout set as null.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from formatting my windows as a last option

Comment: ha! I'm happy to have prevented that

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue can be with method `View()` being called without any parameters which can cause re-rendering the whole Sitecore page again.

Try to add parameter to `View()` like that:

```
return View("/Views/Courses/Index.cshtml");
```

Or whatever is the path of the view you want to return.

---

**EDIT:**

As [@David Masters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254449/david-masters) found, for some reason the issue is with calling `View` instead of `PartialView` method with the full path as a parameter. The correct code is:

```
return PartialView("/Views/Courses/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: Just a piece of text: `This is an index view`

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `return View("/Views/Courses/Index.cshtml");` line and check how many time it is called?

Comment: Anything in the logs? Can you change your controller so it inherits from `Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreController`? Can you check presentation details of your page what components are inside the `main` placeholder?

Comment: I've changed it to PartialView("<fullpath>") rather than View and it works. But this is bizarre as I've previously done with View on other projects and it works fine

Comment: Do you have any idea why View doesn't work? Seems strange that it actually crashes the worker process too... severe.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you try with `View` and passing 2 parameters - full path plus new object as a model object?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include your finding but I have no idea why Sitecore behaves like that in your scenario.

Comment: That's strange, I've mixed and matched Views and PartialViews without any issues so far!

Comment: So have I. Never experienced similar issue before.

Comment: I've figured it out, and I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is something missing in placeholder setting, could you check in path sitecore/layout/placeholder setting?

There should be a placeholder key which you are trying to use.

Hope this will help

Cheers!!